# ordering dates in ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataframe of birthdays and want to order them by soonest date to furthest date.  They seem not to want to graph in order of date.

Here is the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Sara", "Joe", "Matt", "Katie", "Ryan", "Sam"), date = c("2003-03-27", "2004-05-16", "2001-02-02", "2004-05-16", "2002-09-03", "2003-1-17"))
```

What i have tried so far is:

```
ggplot(df[order(df$date),]) +  
geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=date), color = 'black', fill = 'blue', stat = 'identity')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df$name <- with(df, factor(name, levels = name[order(date, name)]))

ggplot(df) +  
  geom_bar(aes(x=name, y=date), color = 'black', fill = 'blue', stat = 'identity')
```

EDIT:

Solution here https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3462

`ggplot(tt, aes(x = data, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  scale_y_datetime(breaks = tt$value, date_labels = "%H:%M:%S") +
  geom_point()`

Comment: this works perfectly. can you explain why the order needs to be by date and name and not just date?

Comment: I used `name[order(date, name)]` instead of `name[order(date)]` in case of ties, but because in this case there isn't you could just use the second